# Site Possibly R7.txt Hacked - Can PHP access root directory on Server?

Tags: php, apache

I'm wondering what sort of access PHP has to the root directory of the server machine running my Apache Webserver. I have been reading up about R7.txt shell attacks (http://www.temme.net/sander/2010/07/30/file-system-permissions-for-apache/) and need to know what could be accessed.

I realize that with R7 and similar script hacks, a hacker could gain access to the top level web directory. Could they get deeper? Would that depend on permission settings for Apache/PHP?

Running:
PHP5
Apache2
OS X Server 10.6.8

However, this is a general non-build specific question.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is safe. If a web-script can get access and write to various places, it could then leverage that to gain full access.

The best & safest thing you can do is wipe the serve and re-install it fresh.

Comment: Bought a new system built around IBMs xserve